# System proxy seems not to work

Tags: proxy

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10.

I've set up the system proxy like this:

[image: System proxy configuration]

However, it seems this does not work since I cannot log into Google account in "online account" (I live in China).

How can I check whether the system proxy is working?

Is there something wrong or do I need to check anything?

Answer (score 2):

Typically I check to see if my proxy is working by finding a site that will tell me what my IP is (such as http://www.whatsmyip.org/).

If this displays the IP of your proxy (or a different IP than it shows if you're not using a proxy) then your proxy should be working.

You may also need to check setting specific to your web browser to be sure it's using the system settings for proxies.

You may also check to be sure websites you're trying to access aren't blocked on the DNS level.  If so you may need to manually specify a different DNS server.